# Return MongoEngine Documents as JSON

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

Not too sure if this is really simple or not, but I can't really find anything on the topic. But, either using the regular MongoEngine library, or even Flask-MongoEngine for my Flask based website, would it be possible to return a MongoEngine document as straight JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 0.8 there are helpers see https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1

in the meantime you have to use pymongo's json_utils directly:

```
from bson import json_util
json_util.dumps(MyDoc._collection_obj.find(MyDoc.objects()._query))
```

Comment: Sweet. Know if there's a way to install mongoengine 0.8 through pip? It seems they only have up to 0.7.7 :(

Comment: Not yet 0.8 is still unstable and in development

Answer (score 4):

Ross's and Jellyflower's workarounds don't work when field projection or ordering is used.

More general workaround:

```
from bson import json_util
json = json_util.dumps(query._cursor)
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct workaround should probably be:

```
from bson import json_util
objects = MyDoc.objects()
json_util.dumps(objects._collection_obj.find(objects._query))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: thanks to [Lo-Tan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269876/lo-tan) for `to_mongo()` method usage suggestion.

Eventually I came up with the following solution:

```
from json import JSONEncoder

from mongoengine.base import BaseDocument


class MongoEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, BaseDocument):
            data = o.to_mongo()
            # might not be present if EmbeddedDocument
            o_id = data.pop('_id', None)
            if o_id:
                data['id'] = str(o_id['$oid'])
            data.pop('_cls', None)
            return data
        else:
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)


# consider `obj` to be MongoEngine object
json_data = json.dumps(obj, cls=MongoEncoder)
```

It uses `to_json()` method, added as the response to the aforementioned [issue](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1).

Comment: Calling to_json() executes to_mongo() (which creates the dictionary you want) and then serializes it, and then you deserialize it, which is fairly inefficient.  I think a better approach is to just use [o.to_mongo()](https://gist.github.com/dhesson/e7def67f01d1de452920), as it gives you an ordered dictionary, and then replace the id with the str value.  Anyways, thanks for the code as it lead me in the right direction!